# “cache-control” values in a HTTP response

Tags: http, firefox, caching, firefox-addon

how to override “cache-control” values in a HTTP response
I have a web page that returns the following header when I access material:

> Cache-Control:no-cache, no-store

Using a firefox extension (like force cors I can't get it working )
I want to modify this response header so that the material is actually cached instead of wasting bandwidth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have recently spent some hours on trying to get a file cached, and discovered that the chrome.webRequest and chrome.declarativeWebRequest APIs cannot force resources to be cached. In no way.

The Cache-Control (and other) response headers can be changed, but it will only be visible in the getResponseHeader method. Not in the caching behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

From some reddit thread:

1. Install "Modify Response Headers" addon for FF:
   https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/modify-response-headers/
2. In the addon's options, go to `headers`. Select `Action` -> `Filter`. In
   the header name field, type `cache-control`, then click `Add`. Do
   the same again but with the header name `pragma`. Then click the
   `Start` button (big button on the top-left).
3. Set these values in `about:config`: `browser.cache.disk.enable` = `false`
   `browser.cache.memory.capacity` = `200000` (you will probably need to
   create this field - right click empty space -> `New` -> `Integer`)
4. Restart Firefox.